# Twilio Play hold music when call is being dialed

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm using a twilio function that plays a message then plays the hold music while dialing call to the numbers but its not dialing the call it just plays the hold music.

```js
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    twiml.play('https://cornsilk-porpoise-7226.twil.io/assets/speech_20231208002827353.mp3');

    twiml.enqueue({ waitUrl: 'http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient' }, 'incoming');
    const dial = twiml.dial();
    dial.queue('incoming');
    dial.number('+16468600135');
    dial.number('+923405998592');

    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

I tried many things and different approches but all in vien

Comment: Is that the full code? Where is the inbound or outbound call that will trigger the dial. Queue('incoming')?

Comment: Yes its the full code I am using this function inside twilio functions and will directly call to this function

Comment: The code provided seems to be trying to handle two calls at the same time. The first call is what is triggering the call to hear an audio file and then be placed on enqueued (and playing the hold music). This is the play then enqueue. To help troubleshoot, I'd suggest a second completely separate function that receives a call and dequeues (dial. Queue('incoming')). 1 function to enqueue and 1 function to dequeue.